# Twitter Profile Geo Enrichment for the UK

Tags: twitter, geolocation, gnip

In the premium operators section of the Twitter API documentation, they have operators that can be used to filter based on the Profile Geo Enrichment data. In particular, you can filter by profile_region. An example being `profile_region:"Zurich"` which worked as expected to return tweets from Users that are based in Zurich. However, `profile_region:"London"` and `profile_region:"Greater London"` both lead to the request returning 0 results. The limitations on the number of these requests that can be made (per month) discouraged me from keep trying things until it worked.

I have searched the Twitter documentation, the old documentation for the API on gnip.com and also the GeoNames.org to try and find what twitters definition of a UK region or simply an example of a place in the UK, however, have been unsuccessful.

I have also used the user/search API to gather user_objects of users located in London to find the derived field (which should contain the Profile Geo Enriched data) but found that this was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of "levels" to profile geo:

- `profile_region`
- `profile_subregion`
- `profile_locality`

If you use `profile_locality:London` you'll see different results (or `profile_subregion:"Greater London"`). The London object looks like this:

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "country_code": "GB",
      "locality": "London",
      "region": "England",
      "sub_region": "Greater London",
      "full_name": "London, England, United Kingdom",
      "geo": {
        "coordinates": [
          -0.12574,
          51.50853
        ],
        "type": "point"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect thank you very much. How did you find the London object? Is there an API call? For example, pulling all objects containing 'London' or all locations that overlap a given geo-coordinate?

Comment: That's an example from a Tweet containing a London object, obtained by using one of the above query filters. No separate API call.